# Reference text for Hilbert space theory.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, hilbert-spaces, book-recommendation

I am searching for a reference that contains a detailed discussion of most of the topics in Hilbert space theory. I am both interested in the geometry of Hilbert spaces and operators on Hilbert spaces.

I am familiar with several excellent texts on Banach space theory; for example, Megginson's *An Introduction to Banach Space Theory* and Albiac & Fanton's *Topics in Banach Space Theory*. However, I am not aware of similar types of books for the theory of Hilbert spaces.

The book that comes most closely to what I have in mind is probably Halmos' *A Hilbert Space Problem Book*. However, as the title of this book indicates, this book is meant as a problem book and not really a reference text.

I am familiar with general topology, abstract measure theory, and functional analysis; so it is no problem if the book has these topics as a prerequisite (as Halmos' book has).

All suggestions and comments are welcome.

Comment: In my operator theory course, we used *Theory of Linear Operators in Hilbert Space* by Akheizer and Glazman. Also, you can find a free text, *Functional Analysis: Spectral Theory* here: http://www.imsc.res.in/~sunder/fa.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Caveat: while these all look promising to me, I haven't read any of them myself.)

- William Arveson, *A Short Course on Spectral Theory* (Springer 2002)
- Bela Bollobas, *Linear Analysis* (2nd ed. Cambridge University Press 1999)
- Ronald G. Douglas, *Banach Algebra Techniques in Operator Theory* (Academic Press 1972 - there's a 2nd ed. from Springer, 1998, apparently not much changed from the 1st ed.)
- Gilbert Helmberg, *Introduction to Spectral Theory in Hilbert Space* (North-Holland, Amsterdam 1969; corr. 2nd pr. 1975; repr. Dover 2008(?))
- N. Young, *An Introduction to Hilbert Space* (Cambridge University Press 1988)

Comment: Thanks. Especially the book by Helmberg seems to be a good reference for the purposes I want to use it for.

Answer (score 0):

My two favorites for the very basics are the following:

- Debnath & Mikusinski, "Introduction to Hilbert Spaces with Applications", 3rd Edition, 2005, Elsevier
- Kreyszig, "Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications", 1978, John Wiley & Sons

You don't need to know measure theory first with these.  They're ideal first books on Hilbert Spaces for people who aren't mathematicians, e.g., instead they are signal processing engineers.